# How to Send Base64-Encoded String with Apache CXF JAX-RS to an External REST API that Accepts a Multipart Attachment?

Tags: java, base64, jax-rs, cxf, attachment

I am implementing an integration to send an incoming message with a Base-64 encoded string of PDF content to an external REST API that accepts an attachment using HTTP multipart/form-data.

There is no issue with plain text but got below error when sending Base-64 encoded string.

"Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream."

Pseudo code:

```
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
    import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment;
    import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.AttachmentBuilder;
    import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.ContentDisposition;

    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http"//External_URI");
    client.type("multipart/form-data");

    // String plainTextRequest = "Plain text in attachment works";

    //  Below string is just the first line of encoded content. Actual content has logo and other data.
    String base64Request =      "JVBERi0xLjQKJaqrrK0KMSAwIG9iago8PAovQ3JlYXRvciAoQXBhY2hlIEZPUCBWZXJzaW9uIDIuNykKL1Byb2R1Y2VyIChBcGFjaGUgRk9QIFZlcnNpb24gMi4................";

    // No issue with below attachment with plain text
    //final Attachment att = new AttachmentBuilder().object(plainTextRequest).contentDisposition(new     //ContentDisposition("form-data; name="notice"; filename="notice.pdf"")).build();

   // Above error when sending attachment with base64 encoded content
   final Attachment att = new AttachmentBuilder().id("notice").object(base64Request).header("Content-  Transfer-Encoding", "base64").mediaType("application/pdf").contentDisposition(new ContentDisposition("form- data; name="notice"; filename="notice.pdf"")).build();

   client.post(att);
```

Apache CXF JAX-RS throws an error when sending attachment with base64 encoded string.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by setting allow chunking policy to be false.

```
HTTPClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
```